# PDF crop even-odd pages with PHP + GhostScript

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I am working in a routine for crop PDF's and import them into a PDF template. I am using GhostScript, invoked with `exec()` from a PHP script, and FPDI. All running server-side.

So far, I am able to crop pdf documents with GhostScript using the procedure explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797841/cropping-a-pdf-adding-crop-box-using-ghostscript) (setting `CropBox`).

The next step is to crop differently the even and odd pages of a document. So I tried the method explained in [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/904332/add-gutter-binding-margin-to-existing-pdf-file) in SuperUser site, passing custom PostScript code into -c parameter to GhostScript:

```
-c "<< /CurrPageNum 1 def /Install { /CurrPageNum CurrPageNum 1 add def 
CurrPageNum 2 mod 1 eq {28 0 translate} {} ifelse } bind  >> setpagedevice"
```

This method shift odd pages 28 pt, and do none for even pages. So, I tried to modify this, passing CropBox(es) (the %s placeholders are replaced with appropriate coordinates in a `sprintf` sentence):

```
-c "<< /CurrPageNum 1 def /Install { /CurrPageNum CurrPageNum 1 add def 
CurrPageNum 2 mod 1 eq {[/CropBox [%s %s %s %s]} {[/CropBox [%s %s %s %s]} 
ifelse } bind  >> setpagedevice"
```

Here is the full command executed over a 4-page pdf file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
-o C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ledrail\tmp\output.pdf 
-c "<< /CurrPageNum 1 def /Install { /CurrPageNum CurrPageNum 1 add def 
CurrPageNum 2 mod 1 eq {[/CropBox [119.04 168.336 505.92 715.428]}
{[/CropBox [59.52 84.168 505.92 715.428]} ifelse } bind >> setpagedevice"
-f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ledrail\documentacio\pdf\documentacio_15.pdf
```

Ovbiously, I get an error, because `[/CropBox...` is not valid PS code.

```
Error: /typecheck in --.postinstall--
```

**EDIT for clarify:**

So, my question is: how can I pass ***the equivalent to*** two CropBox(es) -for odd and even pages- to the PostScript code shown above? Or, there is another method for achieve this **with GhostScript** from command line?

*Obviously, I know CropBox is not PostScript valid code, but what are alternatives?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GhostScript can process PostScript files and PostScript commands passed through -c parameter at command line. So, for achieve things non trivial, you should understand at least the basics of this language.

Get the relevant documentation fom the sources: [PostScript Language Reference Manual, 3rd ed.](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) and the [PostScript Language Tutorial and Cookbook](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/sdk/sample/BlueBook.zip) if you have not seen PostScript in your life (as is mi case).

[KenS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701996/kens) pointed me:

> You need a /EndPage procedure (which does get passed to setpagedevice)
> and that procedure needs to call the pdfmark.

The docs states that **EndPage** is

> A procedure to be executed at the end of each page. Before calling the
> procedure, the interpreter pushes two integers on the operand stack—a
> count of previous showpage executions for this device and a reason
> code indicating the circumstances under which this call is being made:
>
> 0 - During showpage or (LanguageLevel 3) copypage
>
> 1 - During copypage (LanguageLevel 2 only)
>
> 2 - At device deactivation
>
> The procedure must
> return a boolean value specifying whether to transmit the page image
> to the physical output device.

So, this fragment of code (from KenS' [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985557/how-do-i-resize-a-pdf-to-be-exactly-8-5-x-11-inches-using-ghostscript/26989410#26989410))

```
<</EndPage {0 eq {[/CropBox [0 0 612 792] /PAGE pdfmark true}{false}ifelse}>> setpagedevice
```

passes a `CropBox` for current page -with coordinates specified- everytime `EndPage` is invoked with reason 0 (showpage) and returns true. Otherwise, nothing is done and returns false. This *reason code* is the first item in operands stack, and after it is "consumed" in operation `0 eq {true block}{false block} ifelse` (is equal to 0?), there is no more in the stack.

So, the next value in the stack is the number of pages processed. We expand the code with another `ifelse` inside the `true` part of code shown above:

```
{2 mod 0 eq {[/CropBox [0 0 612 792] /PAGE pdfmark true} 
{[/CropBox [50 0 612 792] /PAGE pdfmark true} ifelse}
```

This performs modulus between current page (at top of stack) and 2, then tests if equals 0 (i.e. tests for odd/even page). If even (modulus = 0) passes the first `CropBox`, else the second, and returns true in both cases.

So, the full piece of PostScript code:

```
"<</EndPage {0 eq {2 mod 0 eq {[/CropBox [0 0 612 792] /PAGE pdfmark true}
{[/CropBox [50 0 612 792] /PAGE pdfmark true} ifelse}{false}ifelse}>> setpagedevice"
```

when passed in GhostScript as -c parameter allow us to crop differently even and odd pages of a PDF document, i.e. if we want to supress the extra space for binding of original.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a 'CropBox' in PostScript, because CropBox isn't part of the PostScript language, its PDF-specific.

You need to send a /PAGE pdfmark with a /CropBox, as the first post you reference says. You don't set a /Install.

Comment: I I have omitted to focus on my question. Of course, when I said I could establish a CropBox, I was using:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ledrail\tmp\output.pdf -c "[/CropBox[89.28 126.252 505.92 715.428] /PAGES pdfmark" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ledrail\documentacio\pdf\documentacio_15.pdf`

Comment: You need a /PAGE pdfmark not a /PAGES pdfmark. The PAGES one affects *all* pages

Comment: Thanks, KenS. So, there is any other way -using GhostScript- to determine a range of pages, apart from `-f` and `-l` parameters -which determine consecutive pages? And in the command from my last comment, which page would apply `/PAGE` ?

Comment: -f is simply the end of PostScript input (on the command line). You need to combine your two approaches. You need a /EndPage procedure (which *does* get passed to setpagedevice) and that procedure needs to call the pdfmark. The EndPage procedure gets called with 2 value son the stack, one of them is the number of pages emitted so far. So you cna use that to determine which values to set for the pdfmark. See a previous answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985557/how-do-i-resize-a-pdf-to-be-exactly-8-5-x-11-inches-using-ghostscript/26989410#26989410

Comment: `-c "<</EndPage {0 eq {2 mod 0 eq {[/CropBox [%s %s %s %s] /PAGE pdfmark true} {[/CropBox [%s %s %s %s] /PAGE pdfmark true} ifelse}{false}ifelse}>> setpagedevice"`

Well, that filally worked !!! If I understand the logic correctly (with the aid of PLRM ed.3), the outer `ifelse` tests (0 eq) for `showpage` execution; and the inner `ifelse` (2 mod 0 eq) tests for odd/even pages, supplying the corresponding CropBox when `setpagedevice` is called.

Comment: @Laura: If you found a *completely working* solution, you should also post it as an answer (even if it is to your own question)!